# How to solve Incompatible types in branches with generics

Tags: rust

So the idea [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50855c325e9778d9f80920cdd07ec599) is that I have a reference to the raw binary audio data and I want to process it without creating unnecessary copies.

The data can be either signed 16-bit pcm or floating point 32 bit pcm.

The processing needs to have both of this representations outputting 32 bit floating point slices of of audio data.

```rust
use std::{slice, mem};

fn do_something<'a>(pcm_s16le: &'a [i16], pcm_f32le: &'a [f32]) -> impl Iterator<&'a [f32]> {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn final_step(chunks: impl Iterator<&'a [f32]>) {z
    for chunk in chunks {
        // send to processing
    }
}

fn preprocess<'a>(raw_data: &'a [u8], param: bool) -> &'a [&'a [f32]] {
    let (pcm_s16le, pcm_f32le) = if param {
        let pcm_s16le = slice::from_raw_parts(
            raw_data.as_ptr() as *const i16,
            raw_data.len() / mem::size_of::<i16>()
        );
        let pcm_f32le = pcm_s16le
            .iter()
            .map(|&sample| sample as f32 / 2.0_f32.powi(15))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        (pcm_s16le, &pcm_f32le)
    } else {
        let pcm_f32le = slice::from_raw_parts(
            raw_data.as_ptr() as *const f32,
            raw_data.len() / mem::size_of::<f32>()
        );
        let pcm_s16le = pcm_f32le
            .iter()
            .map(|&sample| (sample * 2.0_f32.powi(15)) as i16)
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        (&pcm_s16le, pcm_f32le)
    };
    do_something(pcm_s16le, pcm_f32le)
}
```

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
8  |       let (pcm_s16le, pcm_f32le) = if param {
   |  __________________________________-
9  | |         let pcm_s16le = slice::from_raw_parts(
10 | |             raw_data.as_ptr() as *const i16,
11 | |             raw_data.len() / mem::size_of::<i16>()
...  |
17 | |         (pcm_s16le, &pcm_f32le)
   | |         ----------------------- expected because of this
...  |
27 | |         (&pcm_s16le, pcm_f32le)
   | |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected slice `[i16]`, found struct `Vec`
28 | |     };
   | |_____- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `(&[i16], &Vec<f32>)`
             found tuple `(&Vec<i16>, &[f32])`
```

There are two problems here:

- Different types in branches.
- When `param` is true pcm_f32le is owned by the current function and slices of it can't be returned from the function.

One way to solve the first problem is to copy raw_data into vector and then both `pcm_s16le` and `pcm_f32le` would be vectors, but this creates unnecessary copy.

The other way to solve the first problem (and probably the second one) is to pass a callback that would do the final processing, which isn't convenient as an API.

There are other ways like creating ad-hoc sum type etc.

The question is is there some clever way to solve this via generics and maybe `Box`?

I've tried using `(Box<dyn AsRef<[i16]>>, Box<dyn AsRef<[f32]>>)` as the type for tuple, but it doesn't work.

It seems to me that there should be a solution here, because both parts of the tuple are basically pointers with length and the only difference is whether they should be deallocated when they go out of scope or not.

As to the final return type It basically an iterator of slices with the only difference is where does underlying data comes from. So it seems like there can be a way to abstract that.

EDIT: I've added `final_step` to maybe clarify the goal I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You should use a `Cow`: something that can either be *borrowed*, `&[T]`, or *owned*, `Vec<T>`. See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c06c90755029132d634281c6b699022c). However, I didn't address your return type, which has... problems, because I didn't know what the `unimplemented!()` part is supposed to do. You mention an iterator of slices, but `[i16]` and `[f32]` are different types...

Comment: @kmdreko
`Cow` seems to be appropriate. I've changed the [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3812336c5fdc3a1c1684eaaade172ed4) to show the problem with returning the data owned by the current function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @kmdreko points out, you can use `Cow` to abstract over the status of slices as owned or borrowed. Once you've done that, the problem is in returning an iterator over data owned by the current function. Any `Vec` created by `preprocess` lives only until the function exists, unless we return it to the caller. But in Rust, you can't return both a value and a reference (in)to that value, and that's exactly what `do_something` returns: an iterator with a reference into the `Vec` created by `preprocess`.

The solution in this case is to create a struct that we can return to the caller, which owns any `Vec`s allocated by `preprocess`. Let's call it `Preprocessed`.

```
struct Preprocessed<'a> {
    pub pcm_s16le: Cow<'a, [i16]>,
    pub pcm_f32le: Cow<'a, [f32]>,
}
```

Now you can implement `preprocess` like this:

```
fn preprocess<'a>(raw_data: &'a [u8], param: bool) -> Preprocessed<'a> {
    if param {
        let pcm_s16le = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(
            raw_data.as_ptr() as *const i16,
            raw_data.len() / mem::size_of::<i16>()
        ) };
        let pcm_f32le = pcm_s16le
            .iter()
            .map(|&sample| sample as f32 / 2.0_f32.powi(15))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        
        Preprocessed {
            pcm_s16le: Cow::Borrowed(pcm_s16le),
            pcm_f32le: Cow::Owned(pcm_f32le),
        }
    } else {
        let pcm_f32le = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(
            raw_data.as_ptr() as *const f32,
            raw_data.len() / mem::size_of::<f32>()
        ) };
        let pcm_s16le = pcm_f32le
            .iter()
            .map(|&sample| (sample * 2.0_f32.powi(15)) as i16)
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        
        Preprocessed {
            pcm_s16le: Cow::Owned(pcm_s16le), 
            pcm_f32le: Cow::Borrowed(pcm_f32le),
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can implement the operation performed by `do_something` as a method returning `impl Iterator` on `Preprocessed`:

```
impl<'a> Preprocessed<'a> {
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &[f32]> {
        // body of do_something goes here
        // you can use `self.pcm_i16le` too if you want of course
        iter::once(&self.pcm_f32le[..])
    }
}
```

So your `main` becomes:

```
fn main() {
    let raw_data = [0u8; 10];
    for x in process(&raw_data, true).iter() {
        dbg!(x);
    }
}
```

Ideally, we could make this even nicer by, rather than using a method like `iter`, implementing `IntoIterator` for `&Processed`, allowing you to write:

```
fn main() {
    let raw_data = [0u8; 10];
    for x in &process(&raw_data, true) {
        dbg!(x);
    }
}
```

The implementation would look like this:

```
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a Processed<'a> {
    type Item = &'a [f32];
    type IntoIter = impl Iterator<Item=&'a [f32]>;
    
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        // body of do_something goes here (instead of on an inherent method)
        iter::once(&self.pcm_f32le[..])
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, at the moment using `impl Trait` in a trait's associated types isn't stable. On nightly compilers, you can enable the experimental feature that permits this by adding `#![feature(min_type_alias_impl_trait)]` to your crate, and the above code will compile.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but it seems to me that this solution isn't zero cost meaning it isn't as efficient as writing two branches with duplicated `do_something` and `final_step` after it or maybe it is?

Comment: @user1685095 The only place I can see any additional overhead would be the branch on the `Cow`'s discriminant when it is to be converted to a slice. But it's easy to implment `iter` so that the branches only happen once for each of `pcm_f32le` and `pcm_i16le`, so it seems fairly negligible. It's also very possible the compiler will inline everything and convert it to the form you described anyway.